# jQuery won't re-enable a button

Tags: jquery, button

I've got a simple Bingo game that I'm writing using jQuery 1.12 and in part of it, I'm disabling a "Get New Card" button (`<button id="new_card">Get a New Card</button>`) with the following line of code:

`$('#new_card').attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

This works in all of the major browsers I have installed (IE11, Edge, FF48 and Chrome52 - all on Windows 10, 64 bit), as expected. However, when a bingo is detected, the portion of the script that should re-enable that button is failing. I've used the following lines of code to attempt to enable the button:

```
          $('#new_card').attr('disabled', false);
          $('#new_card').removeAttr('disabled');
          $('#new_card').prop('disabled', false);
```

In each of the major browsers listed above, all of these methods fail to enable the button. I have `console.log()` statements both before and after these lines of code, and they output to the console, so I know that they're being executed. No errors are showing up, either. Oddly, if I enter any one of those lines of code into the JS console, all three work, in all of the browsers that I can access the console on. They just don't work at run-time. The full context of the code is below:

```
        function newGame() {
            clearInterval(ballTimer);
            bingoCount = 0;
            ballCount = 0;
            selected = [];
            var name = '';
            if ($('#cbNewCard').is(':checked')) newCard();
            ballTimer = setInterval(callBall, 5000);
            gameInProgress = true;
            $('#new_card').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }

        function stopGame() {
          gameInProgress = false;
          $('#new_card').attr('disabled', false);
          $('#new_card').removeAttr('disabled');
          $('#new_card').prop('disabled', false);
          clearInterval(ballTimer);
        }

        function callBall(){
            var num = false;
            do {
                num = getRand(1,75);
                var name = getBall(num);
                console.log(selected.length);
                if (selected.length >= 75) return false;
            } while (findThis(num, selected));
            selected.push(num);
            var newBall = $('<div>').addClass(name).html(name + num);
            $('#called_numbers')
              .append(newBall)
              .animate({scrollTop: $('#called_numbers div:last-child').position().top});
            ballCount++;
            $('#ballCount').text(ballCount);
            check4bingos();
            if (bingoCount > 0) {
                console.log('Got a BINGO!');
                stopGame();
                console.log('Got a BINGO!');
            }
        }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('#new_card').prop('disabled', false);` is the correct way, and definitely does work. (The correct way to disable it is ``$('#new_card').prop('disabled', true);``) Can you turn your code above into a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) so we can point out what's wrong?

Comment: Here's a [mcve] showing it working: https://jsfiddle.net/jn5Lm09z/1/

Comment: Quick and lazy edition, remove and recreate the button every new game

Comment: I'll have to work on the minimal, complete & verifyable version, but in the meantime, what I have is at http://www.geekcavecreations.com/bingo/ - To see the problem, just mark a Bingo (mark any combination of boxes to form one) then hit "New Game". Once the game starts, the button is disabled, but after the bingo is detected, it won't enable.

Comment: `[<button id=​"new_card" disabled=​"disabled">​Get a New Card​</button>​]` 
`$("#new_card").prop("disabled", false);` 
`[<button id=​"new_card">​Get a New Card​</button>​]` Not having problem in the site by Google Chrome console

Comment: As an update, reducing the code to it's barest essentials to illustrate the problem seems to have "fixed" it, so I'll just have to work backwards to find out where it starts failing. Thanks for the tips, folks. I'll report back. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the scopes of your bingoCount.

The top of your script you set bingoCount as a global variable to 0

```
      var ballCount = 0;
      var bingoCount = 0;
      var ballTimer;
      var gameInProgress = false;
      var selected = [];
      var inCard = [];
```

Then in check4bingos() you are trying to enumerate the variable you have `var bingoCount` making the scope local.

***local vs global example:***
https://jsfiddle.net/33y55tpa/

Change the scope in check4bingos by remove the var from bingoCount. Then your condition of when to stopGame() from callBall should apply as from what i can tell your global scope bingoCount will always be 0.

You are also running clearInterval for ballTimer() once the local scope bingoCount > 0 so  the logic of bingoCount > 0 {stopGame()} will never be run as the interval running that logic is removed prior.

```
        if (bingoCount > 0) {
            console.log('Got a BINGO!');
            clearInterval(ballTimer);
        }
```

Comment: I just found that myself, just a moment ago. A stray `var` in the function `check4bingos` was the culprit. I've actually re-coded that function to return a value, rather than alter the variable in the global scope. Thanks!